# How do i display other textview etc in a layout created by an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

hope someone can help. My activity extends ListView and in OnCreate creates an ArrayAdapter. The custom ArrayAdapter class i've written then in its getView function creates each list item to have a textview and checkbox. It does this by inflating a separate layout. Which effectively means the layout for the activity is never used. This all works fine. But ideally i'd also have a textview before this list and a button after it. How/where do i add these!?!

Answer (score 0):

See this link for the details:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

It explains how to do exactly what you are asking for,  use a custom view for the activity and still use the ListActivity class.

> Screen Layout
>
> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)
>
> Optionally, your custom view can contain another view object of any
>   type to display when the list view is empty. This "empty list"
>   notifier must have an id "android:id/empty". Note that when an empty
>   view is present, the list view will be hidden when there is no data to
>   display.